# DateTime format expects parameter 1 to be string, Object given - Symfony2

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having some troubles using the format function in Symfony2 when trying to insert a date interval into a table, for the purpose of setting due dates for created invoices.

Here is what I have:

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$interval = $today->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));
$invoice->setDueDate($interval->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

However, when I hover over the format parameter in PHPStorm, it tells me that it's expecting a DateTime object not a string, and I get the following error in my profiler:

> Error: Call to a member function format() on string

So, I changed the line to this:

```
$invoice->setDueDate($interval->format(new \DateTime()));
```

But when I run that, my profiler gives this error:

> Warning: DateTime::format() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

It almost seems like a catch 22 situation! I am really baffled, do I use a string or a DateTime object, because either one fails yet warns me I need to use one or the other..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d guess that `$invoice->setDueDate()` is the one expecting a `DateTime` instance. So the line should be `$invoice->setDueDate($interval);`

Comment: You are absolutely correct - I only needed the default formatting anyway, so really no need to declare it! Thank you!